# Add padding to top and bottom of cells

Tags: performance, vba, excel

I have a column with variable length text in each of the cells. I have written some code to add padding to the top and bottom of the cells. While the code works well it becomes quite slow when the number of rows is extremely large. Is there a better way of achieving the desired result without looping through each cell?

```
Function padCells()

With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = False
    .DisplayAlerts = False
    .EnableEvents = False
    .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
End With

On Error GoTo resetApp
    
Dim rng As Range
Dim rw As Range

    Set rng = Selection
    
    With rng.Rows
        .WrapText = False
        .AutoFit
        .WrapText = True
        .AutoFit
    End With
    
    For Each rw In rng.Rows
        If rw.RowHeight >= 24 Then
            rw.RowHeight = rw.RowHeight + 10
        Else
            rw.RowHeight = 24
        End If
    Next

resetApp:
With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = True
    .DisplayAlerts = True
    .EnableEvents = True
    .Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
End With

End Function
```

[image: Example of functionality]

Answer (score 2):

First of all I would replace this

```
With rng.Rows
    .WrapText = False
    .AutoFit
    .WrapText = True
    .AutoFit
End With
```

with just this

```
With rng.Rows
    .WrapText = True
    .AutoFit
End With
```

At least in my testing, the 2 lines that I've removed add no value and you get a minor performance gain if you remove them.

**Things to avoid**

In the following scenarios the method runs 20 to 40 times slower:

1. Page Breaks are on
2. Page View is not normal
3. Another worksheet is activated. I know it does not apply to your example because you are working with the current selection which always indicates the current active worksheet but you might decide to change that

All the above need to be addressed.

**Other ways to achieve this**

I don't think there is any other way.

Here is an idea that came up but it doesn't work:

1. Read the whole range into an array (`Dim arr() As variant`) using `arr = rng.Value2`
2. Duplicate the array with `arrCopy = arr`
3. Loop through each value and add a `vbNewLine` before and after each value inside `arrCopy`
4. Write back with `rng.Value2 = arrCopy`
5. AutoFit - this actually has padding because of the extra lines
6. Write back the original values with `rng.Value2 = arr`

This actually runs 60% faster than your method but unfortunately does not work mainly because when writing back the original values the padding is lost as Excel automatically autofits again. Also this won't work properly with formulas and not to mention you might not have permission to write to the range.

So, I don't think you can do this without looping through each row.

**Actual Improvements**

It turns out that if you minimize the book window or if you hide it then you actually gain about 30% in speed.

**Final code**

I would actually refactor this as a method that receives the range as a parameter so that you can reuse it in other scenarios as well. Also, I would check the sheet protection state to be sure the macro can run:

```
Option Explicit

Sub Main()
    On Error Resume Next
    PadCells Selection, 10
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        MsgBox "Pad failed: " & Err.Description, vbInformation, "Failed"
    End If
    On Error GoTo 0
End Sub

Public Sub PadCells(ByVal rng As Range, ByVal verticalPadding As Double)
    Const methodName As String = "PadCells"
    If rng Is Nothing Then
        Err.Raise 91, methodName, "Range not set"
    Else 'Check protection
        Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = rng.Worksheet
        '
        If ws.ProtectContents Then
            If Not ws.ProtectionMode Then
                Err.Raise 5, methodName, "Parent worksheet is macro protected"
            End If
        End If
    End If
    '
    'Store state as is as this method could be called from a higher
    ' method that still requires specific options when this method exits
    Dim drawingOn As Boolean: drawingOn = Application.ScreenUpdating
    Dim alertsOn As Boolean: alertsOn = Application.DisplayAlerts
    Dim eventsOn As Boolean: eventsOn = Application.EnableEvents
    Dim calcState As XlCalculation: calcState = Application.Calculation
    '
    'Turn state off
    If drawingOn Then Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    If alertsOn Then Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    If eventsOn Then Application.EnableEvents = False
    If calcState <> xlCalculationManual Then Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    '
    'Guard against bad scenarios
    On Error GoTo RestoreState
    If ws.Name <> ActiveSheet.Name Then ws.Activate
    ws.DisplayPageBreaks = False
    With ws.Parent.Windows(1)
        Dim wView As XlWindowView: wView = .View
        If wView <> xlNormalView Then .View = xlNormalView
        .Visible = False '30% gain in speed!
    End With
    '
    Const maxRowHeight As Double = 409.5
    Dim rw As Range
    Dim newHeight As Double
    '
    With rng.Rows
        .WrapText = True
        .AutoFit
    End With
    For Each rw In rng.Rows
        If rw.RowHeight >= 24 Then
            newHeight = rw.RowHeight + verticalPadding
            If newHeight > maxRowHeight Then newHeight = maxRowHeight
            rw.RowHeight = newHeight
        Else
            rw.RowHeight = 24
        End If
    Next
RestoreState:
    With ws.Parent.Windows(1)
        If wView <> xlNormalView Then .View = wView
        .Visible = True
    End With
    If drawingOn Then Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    If alertsOn Then Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    If eventsOn Then Application.EnableEvents = True
    If calcState <> xlCalculationManual Then Application.Calculation = calcState
    '
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then Err.Raise Err.Number, methodName, Err.Description
End Sub
```

### Edit #1

@Greedo had the idea in the comments to Union the ranges. Unfortunately that does not work well when rows of same height are not adjacent. However there is value in adding logic for adjacent rows of same height. Here is the updated method:

```
Public Sub PadCells(ByVal rng As Range, ByVal verticalPadding As Double)
    Const methodName As String = "PadCells"
    If rng Is Nothing Then
        Err.Raise 91, methodName, "Range not set"
    Else 'Check protection
        Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = rng.Worksheet
        '
        If ws.ProtectContents Then
            If Not ws.ProtectionMode Then
                Err.Raise 5, methodName, "Parent worksheet is macro protected"
            End If
        End If
    End If
    '
    'Store state as is as this method could be called from a higher
    ' method that still requires specific options when this method exits
    Dim drawingOn As Boolean: drawingOn = Application.ScreenUpdating
    Dim alertsOn As Boolean: alertsOn = Application.DisplayAlerts
    Dim eventsOn As Boolean: eventsOn = Application.EnableEvents
    Dim calcState As XlCalculation: calcState = Application.Calculation
    '
    'Turn state off
    If drawingOn Then Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    If alertsOn Then Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    If eventsOn Then Application.EnableEvents = False
    If calcState <> xlCalculationManual Then Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    '
    'Guard against bad scenarios
    On Error GoTo RestoreState
    If ws.Name <> ActiveSheet.Name Then ws.Activate
    ws.DisplayPageBreaks = False
    With ws.Parent.Windows(1)
        Dim wView As XlWindowView: wView = .View
        If wView <> xlNormalView Then .View = xlNormalView
        .Visible = False '30% gain in speed!
    End With
    '
    Const maxRowHeight As Double = 409.5
    Dim rw As Range
    Dim newHeight As Double
    Dim startRow As Long
    Dim endRow As Long: endRow = 0
    Dim c As Long: c = rng.Rows.Count
    Dim i As Long
    '
    With rng.Rows
        .WrapText = True
        .AutoFit
    End With
    Do
        startRow = endRow + 1
        Set rw = rng.Rows(startRow)
        newHeight = rw.RowHeight
        For i = startRow + 1 To c
            If newHeight <> rng.Rows(i).RowHeight Then Exit For
        Next i
        If i > c Then
            endRow = c
        Else
            endRow = i - 1
        End If
        If startRow < endRow Then Set rw = rw.Resize(endRow - startRow + 1)
        If newHeight >= 24 Then
            newHeight = newHeight + verticalPadding
            If newHeight > maxRowHeight Then newHeight = maxRowHeight
            rw.RowHeight = newHeight
        Else
            rw.RowHeight = 24
        End If
    Loop Until endRow = c
RestoreState:
    With ws.Parent.Windows(1)
        If wView <> xlNormalView Then .View = wView
        .Visible = True
    End With
    If drawingOn Then Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    If alertsOn Then Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    If eventsOn Then Application.EnableEvents = True
    If calcState <> xlCalculationManual Then Application.Calculation = calcState
    '
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then Err.Raise Err.Number, methodName, Err.Description
End Sub
```

Comment: I also wonder if `Union`ing the ranges that have the same final height (24 & maxheight) then resizing all at once might help. Toggling calculations forces a recalc when the sub exits which is slow - resizing doesn't force a calculation so there is no point turning it off

Comment: Copy +paste special formats (including row heights)?

Comment: @Greedo I haven't thought of union. That might work. Unfortunately I don't have the time to test this until next week. The calculation indeed does not need to be turned off and then on but I left it as the OP had it.

Comment: @Greedo I'm not sure how copy+paste special formats would work. Is there such a thing?

Comment: @Greedo Actually, it only took me 5 minutes to test the Union. In a bad scenario (one height for odd rows and another one for even rows) it seems to be taking twice the time to execute tested on 2400 cells probably because the ranges have too many areas. In a good scenario (4 different heights but adjacent) it runs 4 times faster. I think that in a real world scenario you would have different heights all over the place so union would not help with non-adjacent cells

Comment: @Greedo However, I think there is value in this idea without the need for union. Basically while looping through rows, we could apply the height to all adjacent rows that have the same value thus gaining speed if the data allows it. A ```Do``` loop would work

Comment: @Greedo Added section Edit #1 to reflect your idea. Thanks!

Comment: `verticalPadding` was never used.  But Excellent job.  I could not improve on the performance.

Comment: @TinMan Thanks, I was quite in a hurry on Friday to respond and completely missed that I haven't used the parameter. Updated the answer